# My code for mergesort is returning me the same input array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

The following is the code for Mergesort with pivot set as the first element. This code is generating me an output array which is the same as the input.

Python3 code:

```
def mergesort(array):
    length=len(array)
    if(length<=1):
        return (array)
    else:
        mid=length//2
        left=[]
        right=[]
        # print(mid)
        left=mergesort(array[0:mid])
        right=mergesort(array[mid:])
        # print(left, right)
        arr=merge(left,right)
        return (array)

def merge(left,right):

    # print(left, right)
    i=j=0
    # l=len(left+right)
    l1=len(left)
    l2=len(right)
    l=l1+l2
    arr=list()
    for k in range(l):
        if i == l1:
            arr.append(right[j])
            j+=1
        elif j == l2:
            arr.append(left[i])
            i+=1
        elif(left[i] > right[j]):
            arr.append(right[j])
            j=j+1
        elif (left[i] < right[j]):
            arr.append(left[i])
            i=i+1
        # print(array)
    return (arr)

array=list(map(int,input().split()))
# print(array)
print(mergesort(array))
```

This is a screenshot of my program:
[image: This here is a screenshot to my program]

Comment: Is it typo in `merge_sort`:         `arr=merge(left,right)` then return `array` instead of `arr`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in the code:

First, you have a typo in line 14:

```py
def mergesort(array):
    #....
    arr=merge(left,right)
    return (arr) # Not return (array)
```

Second, your code doesn't work with special inputs as you didn't implement `<=` or `>=` case when doing the merge operation. So your code fails to sort `2 5 3 5` for instance. To fix this:

```py
def merge(left,right):
    # ...
    elif(left[i] > right[j]):
        arr.append(right[j])
        j=j+1
    elif (left[i] <= right[j]): # instead of <
        arr.append(left[i])
        i=i+1
```